# How to create a custom shaped gradient?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, cs6, gradient

I have an image that I'd like to blend into another image. Using the gradient tool to draw black on a layer mask works fine, but I'm limited to just straight lines or circles. What I need is a rectangular shape.

I can create a rectangle and then add an inner glow effect, but I can't seem to add that rectangle to my layer mask...

Any help would be great!

I'm using Photoshop CS6.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is one method to create a custom shaded gradient or a gradient along a path**

1. Draw a shape on its own layer:

[image: Step 1 for Curved Gradient]

2. Stroke the shape, it'll start something like this:

[image: Step 2 for Curved Gradient]

3. Adjust to Inside and then Size until it fills your shape. In this example 18 did the trick. Really you can adjust all the way up since it won't go outside the edge anyways.

[image: Step 3 for Curved Gradient]

4. Change from Solid to Gradient and then just adjust as you need to

[image: Step 4 for Curved Gradient]

5. Set the style to Shape Burst

[image: Step 5 for Curved Gradient]

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a linear, black to transparent, gradient and draw inward from the 4 edges of the layer mask.

Another method would be to simply create a hard edge black border on the layer mask then run `Filter > Blur > Radial Blur` on the layer mask.